# What code would let me find the compiled executable's directory?

Tags: delphi

...Even when a user opens an application by double-clicking an associated file in a directory that's different from the executable. I've always used ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName), but this function doesn't work as hoped in this circumstance.

Comment: `ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName)` should work.  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that Vista and Win7 don't permit reading or manipulating files inside \ProgramFiles? (I'm sorry I don't have the actual error message with me now ... the user is elsewhere.)

Comment: Remember that Windows Vista and 7 might work with a VirtualStore system, which might hide the real path and appear like it comes from somewhere else.

Comment: You might wanna look at the following:Making Your Application UAC Aware http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/MakingAppsUACAware.aspx

UAC Virtualization – Allowing standard users to update a system protected area http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2010/08/11/uac-virtualization-allowing-standard-users-to-update-a-system-protected-area.aspx

Comment: -1. Question cannot be answered in its current form. Describe what "doesn't work" means. (You cannot hope to determine or recognize the solution to a problem you cannot describe.)

Comment: I guess you're right, Rob. I'm sorry. I thought there might be some easy alternative function for finding the path in question, or some common error that experts would recognize from the little info I was able to provide. ... I'll wait a little while for any other responses people wish to give & then close the question.

Comment: You don't have to *close* the question; just *fix* it. Tell *what* doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

`ExeName` returns `ParamStr(0)` which in turn returns the string produced by [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx) with `hModule` set to 0. I cannot see any reason why this wouldn't work in a normal application.

Answer (score 0):

Also try ParamStr(0). Maybe that works when application.exename doesn't?

Comment: That's exactly what the `ExeName` property returns.

Answer (score 0):

ExePath := ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0));

I do it all the time, and it always works, whatever OS it is running on.